# React passing props from const to child component

Tags: reactjs, constants, state, map-function

I am a react noob and I need help with a shopping cart I am working on.

I am trying to get button to remove an item from the array of objects I have but don't know how to access it from where it is in the tree.

I mapped over the cartItems variable and got them to display on the page but there is now the case of passing it to another component.

Please be gentle, this is my first post.

Here is the code in App Component:

```
const cartItems =
[
 {
id: 1,
image: image1,
description: 'Cotton Tshirt',
style: 'MS13KT1906',
color: 'blue',
size: 'S',
price: 11.00,
button: <RemoveButton />
  },
{
image: image3,
description: 'Print Girls Tee',
style: 'MS13KT1906',
color: 'pink',
size: 'S',
price: 17.00,
button: <RemoveButton />
},
{
image: image2,
description: 'Flower Pattern Shirt',
style: 'MS13KT1906',
color: 'blue',
size: 'S',
price: 9.00,
button: <RemoveButton />
},
{
image: image4,
description: 'Check Pattern Shirt',
style: 'MS13KT1906',
color: 'red',
size: 'M',
price: 22.00,
button: <RemoveButton />
 }
];

return (
  <div>
 <ItemList         
  cartItems={cartItems.map((item, i) =>
        <ul key={i}>
          <li>
            <img src={item.image} />
          </li>
          <li>
            Description: {item.description}
          </li>
          <li>
            Color: {item.color}
          </li>
          <li>
            Size: {item.size}
          </li>
          <li>
            Price: {item.price}
          </li>
          <li>
            {item.button}
          </li>
        </ul>
      )} />
     <RemoveButton />
      </div>
    );
  }
 }
```

and the code in Remove Button Component

```
 onClickRemove(e, item) {
   console.log(e) <-- what do i do here?
 }

 render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.onClickRemove}>
        X Remove
      </button>
    </div>

    )
   }
  }
```

Comment: I'm assuming the cart and all this is just dummy data for practice, yes? Or is this intended to expand out to a full store eventually?

Comment: it's practice, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have unique key for each object in the array like you have for zero index object.

keep your array of objects in the state so that you can remove an object and do setState again to see updated data.

You should keep your event handler function where you are iterating your data and pass the event handler function as props to RemoveButton. This will work as a callback in reactjs.

I prefer the below way of implementing such things

```
class CartItems extends Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        cartItems: []
      }
    }

    componentWillMount(){
      const cartItems =
        [
         {
        id: 1,
        image: image1,
        description: 'Cotton Tshirt',
        style: 'MS13KT1906',
        color: 'blue',
        size: 'S',
        price: 11.00,
        button: <RemoveButton />
          },
        {
        id: 2,
        image: image3,
        description: 'Print Girls Tee',
        style: 'MS13KT1906',
        color: 'pink',
        size: 'S',
        price: 17.00,
        button: <RemoveButton />
        },
        {
        id: 3,
        image: image2,
        description: 'Flower Pattern Shirt',
        style: 'MS13KT1906',
        color: 'blue',
        size: 'S',
        price: 9.00,
        button: <RemoveButton />
        },
        {
        id: 4,
        image: image4,
        description: 'Check Pattern Shirt',
        style: 'MS13KT1906',
        color: 'red',
        size: 'M',
        price: 22.00,
        button: <RemoveButton />
         }
        ];
        this.setState({
          cartItems: cartItems
        });
    }

    onClickRemove(id, image) {
      let items = this.state.cartItems;
      items = items.filter((item) => {
        return item.id !== id;
      });
      this.setState({
        cartItems: items
      });
    }

    render(){
      return (
        <div>
          <ItemList cartItems={this.state.cartItems.length> 0 && this.state.cartItems.map((item, i) =>
              <ul key={i}>
                <li>
                  <img src={item.image} />
                </li>
                <li>
                  Description: {item.description}
                </li>
                <li>
                  Color: {item.color}
                </li>
                <li>
                  Size: {item.size}
                </li>
                <li>
                  Price: {item.price}
                </li>
                <li>
                  {item.button}
                </li>
              </ul>
            )} />
           <RemoveButton onClickRemove={this.onClickRemove(item.id, item.image)}/>
            </div>
          );
    }

}
```

Remove Button component

```
class RemoveButton extends Component{
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.onClickRemove}>
          X Remove
        </button>
      </div>

      )
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any variable that's "alive" needs to be in state somewhere. Here's an example cart app that that has you cart in state.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Cart />
    </div>
  );
}

class Cart extends React.Component {
  state = {
    inCart: [
      {
        id: 1,
        description: "Cotton Tshirt",
        style: "MS13KT1906",
        color: "blue",
        size: "S",
        price: 11
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        description: "Print Girls Tee",
        style: "MS13KT1906",
        color: "pink",
        size: "S",
        price: 17
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        description: "Check Pattern Shirt",
        style: "MS13KT1906",
        color: "red",
        size: "M",
        price: 22.5
      }
    ]
  };

  // or just pass the id, and make the check `(product.id !== removedProductId)`
  removeCallback = removedProduct => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      inCart: state.inCart.filter(product => product.id !== removedProduct.id)
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { inCart } = this.state;

    if (!inCart.length) {
      return (
        <p>Cart is empty.</p>
      );
    }

    return (
      <table>
        {inCart.map(product => (
          <CartRow
            key={product.id}
            product={product}
            removeCallback={this.removeCallback}
          />
        ))}
      </table>
    );
  }
}

class CartRow extends React.Component {
  removeOnClick = removedProduct =>
    this.props.removeCallback(this.props.product);

  render() {
    const { product, removeCallback } = this.props;

    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{product.description}</td>
        <td>{product.price}</td>
        <td>
          <RemoveButton onClick={this.removeOnClick} />
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

class RemoveButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <button {...this.props}>Remove</button>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Two things to highlight are:

1. All items need some unique identifier (in this case `id`)
2. We pass callback props to modify state that's somewhere higher up in our tree. (this callback uses our unique identifier to pass a new object with the removed item filtered out)

---

However, I would *strongly* encourage considering [avoiding arrays of objects, and flattening your data](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/normalizingstateshape). Instead of an array of objects, you'd have an object keyed by id (for easy access) and arrays of ids that represent groups of those items. In a full app, you probably have something called `products` that represents *all* your items for sale. And your cart would just be those added to buy. So `products` would be our id-keyed object, and `inCart` would just be an array of the ids. Here's an example cart app with that shape (with products on the highest component, as it's likely used throughout your app):

```js
function App() {
  const products = {
    1: {
      id: 1,
      description: "Cotton Tshirt",
      style: "MS13KT1906",
      color: "blue",
      size: "S",
      price: 11
    },
    2: {
      id: 2,
      description: "Print Girls Tee",
      style: "MS13KT1906",
      color: "pink",
      size: "S",
      price: 17
    },
    4: {
      id: 4,
      description: "Flower Pattern Shirt",
      style: "MS13KT1906",
      color: "blue",
      size: "S",
      price: 9
    },
    9: {
      id: 9,
      description: "Check Pattern Shirt",
      style: "MS13KT1906",
      color: "red",
      size: "M",
      price: 22.5
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Cart products={products} />
    </div>
  );
}

class Cart extends React.Component {
  state = {
    inCart: [1, 2, 9]
  };

  removeCallback = removedId => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      inCart: state.inCart.filter(productId => productId !== removedId)
    }));
  };

  // for testing only
  refillCart = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      inCart: [1, 2, 9]
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { products } = this.props;
    const { inCart } = this.state;

    if (!inCart.length) {
      return (
        <p>
          Cart is empty. <button onClick={this.refillCart}>Refill?</button>
        </p>
      );
    }
    return (
      <table>
        {inCart.map(productId => (
          <CartRow
            key={productId}
            products={products}
            productId={productId}
            removeCallback={this.removeCallback}
          />
        ))}
      </table>
    );
  }
}

class CartRow extends React.Component {
  removeOnClick = removedId => this.props.removeCallback(this.props.productId);

  render() {
    const { products, productId, removeCallback } = this.props;
    const product = products[productId];

    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{product.description}</td>
        <td>{product.price}</td>
        <td>
          <RemoveButton onClick={this.removeOnClick} />
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

class RemoveButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <button {...this.props}>Remove</button>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

This way, `inCart` is short and clear and modifying it just requires filter the array.

One seeming "negative" to this might be that you have to keep passing `products` down the tree. However, a) passing stuff down the tree is React's thing, b) it's *very* likely as your app grows you'll start use some sort of global state library (like Redux) or [React's context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), and connect each component to that global state as needed. At that stage, you don't need to keep passing `products` down, but instead "import" it into the component as needed (and instead of passing callbacks down, you'd have global actions to modify global state).

Comment: Don't mean to seemingly get off topic talking about Redux/global state but I think it's relevant when talking about flattening your state which is pertinent to the question in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I realize my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52014183/5812047) sort of skips over the question of how to let `onClickRemove` know *which* item it's removing when you're looping over your items. There are three ways I know of doing it:

**1. Pass an anonymous function with the argument passed (or bind the argument)**

```
<RemoveButton onClick={() => this.onClickRemove(item)}>
// or: <RemoveButton onClick={this.onClickRemove.bind(this, item)}>
```

This may come with a [*fairly minor* performance hit](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md).

**2. Use [currying](https://hackernoon.com/currying-in-js-d9ddc64f162e) - a function that takes your argument and returns another function**

So in `onClick` you're actually calling a method:

```
<RemoveButton onClick={this.onClickRemove(item)}>
```

And that method is a function that takes item, then returns *another* function that handles removing it:

```
onClickRemove = (item) => () => { /* do something with `item` */ }
```

This avoids the performance hit that option 1 has. But, to be honest, I've *never* seen it in the wild; only as an example. Maybe people doesn't know or care about the performance hit, or just find this syntax less appealing, or just didn't think of it.

**3. *(Recommended)* Avoid the situation altogether by instead creating a new component on each loop (which takes the item as a prop)**

This is what the [React ESLint library recommends](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md#lists-of-items) and we've done with:

```
{inCart.map(productId => (
    <CartRow
      key={productId}
      products={products}
      productId={productId}
      removeCallback={this.removeCallback}
    />
))}
```

Now that it's its own component, your `<CartRow />` component can do `<RemoveButton onClick={this.removeOnClick} />` with the `removeOnClick` method being:

`removeOnClick = removedId => this.props.removeCallback(this.props.productId);`

Since you've passed *only* that product, we can hardcode in that method which product we're removing. (It's also arguably just a good place to break up your components.)

Answer (score -1):

This code structure isn't that efficient and I highly recommend you don't actually use this in production, but still using the same architecture you've set up you could pass  the item index down to the  component.

for example

```
<ItemList         
  cartItems={cartItems.map((item, i) =>
        <ul key={i}>
          <li>
            <img src={item.image} />
          </li>
          <li>
            Description: {item.description}
          </li>
          <li>
            Color: {item.color}
          </li>
          <li>
            Size: {item.size}
          </li>
          <li>
            Price: {item.price}
          </li>
          <li>
            {item.button}
          </li>
        </ul>
      )} />
     <RemoveButton index={i} /> // i = index in the Object Array
      </div>
    );
```

The RemoveButton component now knows what index it's associated with. Now in your Component, you can grab that index and do something with it such as

```
 onClickRemove(index) {
   // do something with index.
 }

 render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.onClickRemove.bind(this, this.props.index}>
        X Remove
      </button>
    </div>

    )
   }
  }
```

It's better to use the `bind` method as a lambda expression could potentially have negative performance issues. Read more about binding [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56) and more about Component and Props [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

This is a bit messy. It's better to let the parent handle the onClick function as it has access to the current ItemList and could modify it if it wasn't a const. However I don't know the use case so this could be perfectly valid!

Comment: "It's better to use the `bind` method as a lambda expression could potentially have negative performance issues." Both would have a similar performance impact (as the article states). Binding in the _constructor_ wouldn't, but still leaves the issue of how to pass the argument.